# how to display the colon in reactjs using ternary operator?

Tags: reactjs

In react i want to show some text based on ternary condition. How will i show?
For example,

```
{true?<p>Address:</p>:<p></p>}
```

I want to display **Address:** using of ternary operator. If any solution provide

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more? In JSX this should work: `<div>{ true ? <p>sometext:</p> : <p></p>}</div>` or simply `<p>{ condition ? 'trueText' : 'falseText'}</p>` [Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/91172/)

Comment: <div>{ true ? <p>sometext:</p> : <p></p>}</div> this will not be worked. i just want to display some text with colon base on true condition

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your particular problem. The posted code may not be useful for your use case and your context, but It works as is: [see the demo](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/91172/). Build [a simple example that shows your error](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and explain your use case, It's not clear what problem/error you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of ternary operator you can use conditional operator like this,

```
{ true && <p>Address:</p> }
```

Comment: Note that this actually returns `false`, and overuse of this can leave you ending up with `false` in weird places. More than a few times we've ended up the word "false" itself being rendered.

Comment: oh..i haven't came across such situations yet..but still will take into account